# Pandas dataframe dates off by one day

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I noticed that if I have pandas datetime index inside a pandas dataframe, the value of the dates changes when I call them by using .value

Example.

```
import pandas as pd

date_try=pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01',end='2017-05-01',freq='MS')
date_df=pd.DataFrame(date_try)

print(date_df)
```

[image]

Now notice how the date values change when I call

```
print(date_df.values)
```

[image]

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? I cannot reproduce this on 0.20

Comment: That's OK - that's how Numpy shows datetime's...

Comment: My version is 0.15.2 and I am restricted to using this version.

Comment: @MaxU Well, its giving me trouble since its giving me a wrong date. So I am hoping there is a way to get around this

Comment: What you see is the difference between GMT and your local time (time zone -8 in winter, -7 in summer). When it is midnight of 2017-01-01 in Greenwich, it is still 4PM of 2016-12-31 locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DYZ is right, I run into this all the time setting up cronjobs on my aws box, where the time it's run doesn't correspond to what the source-file says is the time because it was produced in a different timezone You can try to re-index it in local time.

```
import pytz
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
df.index = index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(eastern)
```